# First item on center and second item at last in flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Pretty common question I guess, but couldn't find any solution to fix it.

Code is:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-item">A</div>
  <div class="second-item">B</div>
</div>
```

**Should look like this:**

[image]

`first-item` will be at middle and `second-item` should be at last.

**What I've tried:**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container .second-item {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

How could I achieve it using `flex` or in any other way of `css`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try that,

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container .second-item {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-item">A</div>
  <div class="second-item">B</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Almost: you just need to add a margin `auto` on the first element

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.first-item {
  margin: auto;
}
.second-item {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pxXpjo)

Comment: In your Codepen, change "B" into "Lorem Ipsum" and you'll see "A" is not in the center.

Comment: A is centered with respect of the space available. If the second element is larger this space decreases. And, as per the OP image, the X is centered on the available space (not the full width). A solution with position absolute is fine if you know what you're doing because it could cause overlapping elements easier (B is removed form the flow)

Comment: I doubt that's OP's requirement. But if it is, I'm sure OP will accept your solution because it's the cleanest one.

Comment: What is the `align-self: flex-end;` on the second item for? The `margin: auto` already seems to do the trick. Is this for (other) browser support? (I'm using Chrome)